# Stein's Complex analysis page 44 Example 2

Tags: complex-analysis

In Stein's Complex analysis book, example 2 of page 44 says

$f(z)$ = $\frac{(1-\exp(iz))}{z^2}$ = $\frac{-iz}{z^2}$ + $E(z)$

where $E(z)$ is bounded as z $\to$ 0.

Of course, z is complex variable.

I can not understand why $E(z)$ is bounded like that. Could you help me to understand this?

Comment: Use series definition for exp and get the series for $E(z) $. The bounded nature of $E(z) $ will be obvious after that.

Comment: It's just the Taylor series for $e^{iz}.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1 - e^{iz}}{z^2} = \frac{1 - (1 + iz + \frac{1}{z}(iz)^2 + \ldots)}{z^2} = -iz + \frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty}\frac{(-iz)^k}{k!} $$

You can see pretty well that the term

$$\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty}\frac{(-iz)^k}{k!} = E(z)$$

Is bounded for $z\to 0$.

Expand the sum and watch.

Comment: thank u though some typos which are easily correctable.